# How to calculate the topographic error fur SuperSOM made with the kohonen package?

Tags: r, som, self-organizing-maps

I am using the supersom function (kohonen package, version 3.0.12) and would like to calculate the Topographic error for my map.
I know that there is the package called aweSOM for calculating the Topographic error but it is not able to take the supersom object, only the standard som object from the kohonen package.
Is there any way how I could compute the Topographic error for my supersom map in R?

I tried to calculate the Topographic Error with the somQuality (aweSOM package) but the problem is that the supersom function takes the data as a list of data matrices and the aweSOM can only take the data as a data matrix.
I got the following error message:

```
Error in traindat - som$codes[[1]][bmu, ] : non-conformable arrays
```